# Losses and Accuracy could not improve

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Im trying to train a Product Detection model with approximately 100,000 training images and 10,000 test images. However no matter what optimizer i used in my model, i have tried Adam, SGD with multiple learning rates, my loss and accuracy does not improve. Below is my code

First i read the train images

```
for x in train_data.category.tolist():
    if x < 10:
        x = "0" + str(x)
        path = os.path.join(train_DATADIR,x)
    else:
        x = str(x)
        path = os.path.join(train_DATADIR,x)
    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,str(train_data.filename[idx])), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(100,100))
    train_images.append(new_array) 
    idx += 1
    print(f'{idx}/105392 - {(idx/105392)*100:.2f}%')
narray = np.array(train_images)
```

then i save the train_images data into a binary file

```
np.save(DIR_PATH + 'train_images_bitmap.npy', narray)
```

then i divide the train_images by 255.0

```
train_images = train_images / 255.0
```

and declared my model with input nodes of 100x100 as the images are resized to 100x100

```
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(100, 100)),
keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
keras.layers.Dense(42)
])
```

then i compile the model, i tried adam, SGD(lr=0.01 up to 0.2 and as low to 0.001)

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Next i fit the model with a callback of the epoch

```
model.fit(train_images, train_labels,epochs=2000)
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,monitor='val_acc',
mode='max',save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, verbose=1)
```

but the output i got on the epoch wasnt improving, how can i improve the loss and accuracy? below is the output on the epochs

```
Epoch 6/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 3.7210 - accuracy: 0.0249
Epoch 7/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 3.7210 - accuracy: 0.0248
Epoch 8/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 3.7209 - accuracy: 0.0255
Epoch 9/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 3.7209 - accuracy: 0.0251
Epoch 10/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 3.7210 - accuracy: 0.0254
Epoch 11/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 3.7209 - accuracy: 0.0254
Epoch 12/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 3.7210 - accuracy: 0.0243
Epoch 13/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 12s 3ms/step - loss: 3.7210 - accuracy: 0.0238
Epoch 14/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 11s 3ms/step - loss: 3.7210 - accuracy: 0.0251
Epoch 15/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 3.7209 - accuracy: 0.0253
Epoch 16/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 11s 3ms/step - loss: 3.7210 - accuracy: 0.0243
Epoch 17/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 3.7210 - accuracy: 0.0247
Epoch 18/2000
3294/3294 [==============================] - 12s 3ms/step - loss: 3.7210 - accuracy: 0.0247
```

Comment: use CNN models to train image data. like ResNet, VGG16, etc. They contained hidden layers and fully connected layers which gives good results

Comment: Example of using CNN model https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1k-rnJFxGR7WbS2KfIvJ-IZ_w18m9qdPJ?usp=sharing.

Comment: with the code you have provided in the example, the error i got was 
 'Error when checking input: expected conv2d_19_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (105392, 224, 224)'
though i dont understand the arguments in the conv2d layer, even after reading its documentation

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the choice of optimizer is the main problem. With only a little experience on the matter, I can only suggest some things:

- For images i would try using a 2d-convolution layer before the dense layer.
- Try adding a dropout-layer to reduce the possibility of overfitting.
- The first layer is 100*100, and a reduction to 128 is perhaps to aggressive (i dont know, but thats at least my intuition) Try increasing from 128 to a larger number, or even add an intermediate layer :)

Perhaps something like:

````
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(...))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(...)
    model.add(Dropout(...))
    model.add(Flatten(...))
    model.add(Dense(...))
    model.compile(...)```
````

Comment: im actually pretty new to this and im doing this project because of a coding competition i signed up for, can u explain to me what intermediate layers do? i read the documentations but i dont fully understand them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, sorry i just meant an additional Dense layer as intermediate, since the dimensionality reduction from 100*100 to 128 is quite drastic. I see that the other comments also suggests using a convolutional layer, so I would try doing that (you can try the proposed model i wrote for example)

Comment: alright thanks! Sorry for the late reply haha, can i know whats the difference with the model i have and convolutional model?

Comment: [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitively-understanding-convolutions-for-deep-learning-1f6f42faee1) is a good introduction to Convolution layers :) They are great partly because they tend to find general local features of the image. Check out [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/dense-or-convolutional-part-1-c75c59c5b4ad) blog mini-series for a comparison of dense vs convolutional layers.